# Error creating bean for all of my classes in Spring Boot JPA for MySQL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to setup a simple endpoint for accessing a MySQL database, with one createAccount() method, but it seems as if Spring Boot is not able to wire/create beans through all of my classes.

Here's the code details:

**MykitchenresourcesApplication**

```java
package com.it326.mykitchenresources;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.it326.mykitchenresources.*")
@EntityScan("com.it326.mykitchenresources.*")  
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.it326.mykitchenresources.*")
public class MykitchenresourcesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MykitchenresourcesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**AccountController**

```java
package com.it326.mykitchenresources.controllers;

// Imports

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    private final AccountService accountService;

    @Autowired
    public AccountController(AccountService accountService) {
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createAccount(@RequestBody AccountDTO accountDTO) {
        // Retrieve values from the DTO (Data Transfer Object)
        String name = accountDTO.getName();
        String username = accountDTO.getUsername();
        String password = accountDTO.getPassword();

        // Create the account
        Account createdAccount = accountService.createAccount(name, username, password);

        if (createdAccount != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Account created successfully");
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Failed to create account");
        }
    }
}
```

**AccountService**

```java
package com.it326.mykitchenresources.services;

// Imports

@Service
public class AccountService {
    
    @Autowired
    private final AccountDb accountDb;

    public AccountService(AccountDb accountDb) {
        this.accountDb = accountDb;
    }

    public Account createAccount(String name, String username, String password) {
        Account account = new Account();
        account.setName(name);
        account.setUserName(username);
        account.setHashedPassword(hashPassword(password));
        return accountDb.save(account);
    }

    private String hashPassword(String password) {
        // Generate a salt and hash the password using BCrypt
        String salt = BCrypt.gensalt();
        return BCrypt.hashpw(password, salt);
    }
}
```

**AccountDb (my repository class)**

```java
package com.it326.mykitchenresources.dbs;

// Imports

@Repository
public interface AccountDb extends JpaRepository<Account, Integer> {
    Account findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**Account (my entity class)**

```java
package com.it326.mykitchenresources.entities;

// Imports

@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "account_id")   
    private int accountId;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 45)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "username", length = 45)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "hashed_password", length = 45)
    private String hashedPassword;
    
    // Constructors, getters, setters, etc.
    public Account(){}

    public Account(int accountId, String name, String username, String hashedPassword){
        this.accountId = accountId;
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.hashedPassword = hashedPassword;
    }
    
    public int getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }
    public void setAccountId(int accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUserName(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getHashedPassword() {
        return hashedPassword;
    }
    public void setHashedPassword(String hashedPassword) {
        this.hashedPassword = hashedPassword;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url= // My URL is here.
spring.datasource.username= // Same with my username
spring.datasource.password= // And my password
server.port=8081
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.it326</groupId>
    <artifactId>mykitchenresources</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mykitchenresources</name>
    <description>Backend for myKitchen</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Password Hashing Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version> <!-- or the latest version available -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database Connection Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.7.Final</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version -->
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Testing Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've tried throwing all of my classes into the same package as the main application, but it seems that this does not remedy my issue.

I've also just tried `mvn clean install` without any of the classes as a sanity check that my main application was working okay, and it worked fine.

**The logs and error I'm getting:**

```
o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - 
cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController' defined in file [C:\Users\...\target\classes\com\it326\mykitchenresources\controllers\AccountController.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'accountService' defined in file [C:\Users\...\target\classes\com\it326\mykitchenresources\services\AccountService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'accountDb' defined in com.it326.mykitchenresources.dbs.AccountDb defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on MykitchenresourcesApplication: Not a managed type: class com.it326.mykitchenresources.entities.Account
```

This is my first time setting up a Spring Boot project on my own, so I may be missing something completely obvious and staring me in the face; any help and pointers would be well appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Any reason why you're adding `@ComponentScan`, `@EntityScan`
 and `@EnableJpaRepositories` to your  main class? Spring Boot already automatically scans for components, entities and repositories within the same package (or a subpackage) of the main class. And considering that your main class seems to be in the base package, I don't think you need any of those.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should also remove the `hibernate-core` dependency (it's already included in `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`) and `junit` (already included in `spring-boot-starter-test`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in the comment you should **remove** the explicit dependency to `hibernate-core`. This one:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.7.Final</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version -->
</dependency>
```

After doing it you should **check all imports** used in your classes. Especially the entity classes. There should be no imports from `javax.persistence` package. Only from `jakarta.persistence`. Otherwise you will have a mismatch of objects and errors like this: `not a managed type`.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to autowire your AccountDB in the constructor of `AccountService`

```java
@Service
public class AccountService {

    private final AccountDb accountDb;

    @Autowired // <-- Added a @Autowired annotation.
    public AccountService(AccountDb accountDb) {
        this.accountDb = accountDb;
    }

    public Account createAccount(String name, String username, String password) {
        Account account = new Account();
        account.setName(name);
        account.setUserName(username);
        account.setHashedPassword(hashPassword(password));
        return accountDb.save(account);
    }

    private String hashPassword(String password) {
        // Generate a salt and hash the password using BCrypt
        String salt = BCrypt.gensalt();
        return BCrypt.hashpw(password, salt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, just added that to my code! However, I added that and still yield the same "Error creating bean" error unfortunately.

Comment: As of Spring 4.3, classes with a single constructor can omit the `@Autowired` annotation.